# "Mutated while being enumerated" error shows up semi-randomly in Titanium project

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I'm sure you've all seen this error before in your Titanium mobile projects. I've been getting it in an app I'm working on. It is usually thrown by the same type of operation, but not all the time and not in the same place. I'm wondering if anyone has found a solution to this issue yet.

The error is usually generated when I am iterating through an array of objects, and using that data to create views. Each new view is below its previous sibling, so the new view's top property looks something like this:

```
top = (from_top + old_view.height + 10);
```

As you can see I'm using the view.height property to figure out my top property, and I assume this is part of the problem. Anyone had any luck with this, or are you using a work around to avoid using a view's height property in addition?

(This is also posted on the [Appcelerator Q&A site](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/107091/mutated-while-being-enumerated-error-shows-up-semi-randomly))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use layout: 'vertical' instead of manually specifying the heights? It isn't in the docs at the moment, but as of 1.5 you can specify layout: 'vertical' on windows and scrollviews, possibly on views as well. Works on both iOS and Android.

Comment: I've converted my current project to layout: 'vertical' and it worked very well. Also sped up a few things. For posterity, I posted your answer to the Appcelerator Q&A post as well.